# JPasswordField focus issue

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpasswordfield

I wrote a very simple logon JPanel following the demo in http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html

it has three components,

1. JTextField to get username
2. JPasswordField to get password
3. JButton to logon

then the JPanel is shown in the JFrame when the application starts. the issue is, I found if I click on password field first, i can enter password without problem. however if I enter username first then I can't enter anything in the password field.  anyone knows what might be going wrong here?

here is the the code I wrote for the logon panel, this code can be compiled and run, but the password can't be entered. is there something I missed?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Logon extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField fldName;
    private JPasswordField fldPasswd;
    private JButton btnLogon;

    public Logon() {

        JLabel labTitle = new JLabel("title");
        labTitle.setText("EMT Monitor v.1.0");

        // username
        fldName = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel labName = new JLabel("Username");
        labName.setText("Username:");
        labName.setLabelFor(fldPasswd);

        // passwd
        fldPasswd = new JPasswordField(10);
        fldPasswd.setActionCommand("Logon");
        fldPasswd.addActionListener(this);
        fldPasswd.requestFocusInWindow();

        JLabel labPasswd = new JLabel("Password");
        labPasswd.setText("Password:");
        labPasswd.setLabelFor(fldPasswd);

        // botten
        btnLogon = new JButton("Logon");
        btnLogon.setActionCommand("Logon");
        btnLogon.addActionListener(this);


        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();


        btnLogon.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));

        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(340, 190));

        mainPanel.add(labName);
        mainPanel.add(fldName);
        mainPanel.add(labPasswd);
        mainPanel.add(fldPasswd);
        mainPanel.add(btnLogon);

        JPanel outPanel = new JPanel();
        outPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        outPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

        outPanel.add(mainPanel);
        add(outPanel);

        setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        setVisible(true);
    }



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        if (cmd.equals("Logon")) { //Process the password.

            String user = fldName.getText();
            String passwd = new String(fldPasswd.getPassword());

            System.out.println(user + " " + passwd);


        }


    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Logon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        final Logon newContentPane = new Logon();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a bug in your program code.

Comment: Sounds **very** unusual.

Comment: If you post the code you wrote, that would help us figure out what's wrong. It sounds very unusual, as if you used the wrong variable or method somewhere.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, but when the code has been fixed such that it compiles, it does not show the deviant behavior that you have described. It works fine for me. Please tell us more.

Comment: sorry i copied it from my netbeans project. now the posted code can compile and run, and only the username can get focus.

Comment: I can't replicate your bug. I compiled and ran your code, entered something into the username field and was then able to enter something into the password field, both by clicking into the field and tabbing into it. Try recompiling your code and running it again?

Comment: I'm running the code on linux, which platform r u running? I just found that if you click on button first, the both fields work, otherwise only the usename works. Could it be some focus issue where the components can't get focus?

Comment: Can't replicate the bug. I don't have focus issues Which Java version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. No issues here.

Comment: i found a solution, after creating the logon panel and added it to jframe. call logonpanel.requestFocusInWindow(), then it can function.

Comment: `btnLogon.setActionCommand("Logon");` This might be unnecessary here. Because the text on the button itself acts as action command and you've set the same thing here!

Answer (score 0):

> There is no problem as described in the question. This works fine. Once you enter the username and password, and click logon, the given username and password is printed.